# Is there default knowledge base portlet in Liferay portal

Tags: liferay, portlet

So, hello everyone.
My question itself is already written in the Title.

I could find just some information about it, but don't know how to embed
this portlet to portal.

Does anybody know, where I can find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on Liferay's [Marketplace](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace), in versions for [CE](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15197613) and [EE](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15100561). Of course, you could also use the Wiki, the Messageboard or even standard Webcontent for building a knowledge base, but this would match best by name.

It's from Liferay, so close enough to being "default", even though it's not contained in the core itself. You add it to the page like any other portlet